# Prevent non-privileged user from changing file extension and invocation parameters

Tags: windows, file-permissions, local-area-network

On an office LAN, I want to install an MS-Access database. I will place the database in its own hidden folder. On another folder (folder1), I will place a link to the hidden db file in folder1 (hidden from all users except super user).

for any user except the super user, I would like that users be allowed only to click on the link on folder2 (to start the db application in folder1) but *not to open the link properties or change them or see them*. I don't want non super user to know where the db the link is pointing to exists and I don't want them to either change the parameter on the link such as (/runtime).

This would not be the only 'security' measure, I intend to add more measures such as password for the database and user-level security in the application.

Is this possible?

I currently have no access to any LAN, so I had to ask. Thx.

Comment: Are you talking about a junction or a link? I think a junction may help achieve your goals.

Comment: @NickYoung, reading about junctions here, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 - I can't see the benefit?

Comment: You are essentially trying to hide the path from the user correct? A junction acts much like a Symbolic Link in linux, the user would see the file as if it exists in folder B, so would programs and such, but in fact it exists in folder A.

Comment: @NickYoung, sounds right, but I think for juncion to work, Both link and target must be on local volumes. Also, a Junction points to a folder not to a specific file (as in my case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm getting you right this can be done by removing the "Read Extended Attributes" privilege from the users in question.

You should be able to do the following:

1. Open the link properties, Security Tab
2. Click on "Advanced"
3. Choose Edit or Add to change permissions
4. On the right hand side click on "Show advanced permissions"
5. Remove the "Read extended attributes" permission

The settings above will hide the "Shortcut" tab from the users you configure which might be what you want.

Edit: I should add, this is most definitively only security by obscurity and anyone really wanting to find the original database file will find a way around this (ie: looking at open filehandles, maybe even MS Access "File open history will give this away)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I agree about the "obscurity" part. However securing MS-Access is troublesome. If this works I am not sure how could the non-privileged user get MS-Access file open history?

Comment: What I was trying to say (and I can only guessas I have no Access on my hands atm) that there *might* be some kind of "recently opened files" menu which the users might have access to and which *might* contain the path to the database file.

Comment: One more question please. Could the user have access to the link but not to the file where the link is pointing to? I mean the user will click on the link to start the program, this (may) require privileges for the location where the program is located. What do you think?

Comment: I'd think this is not possible. I think there are at least two privileges involved: 

1. Read / Execute on the executable (MS Access) 
2. At least Read permissions for the database file (it's likely they'll also need write permission if they should be able to add / change / remove data in that said database)

If you remove the latter, users won't be able to open the file.

Answer (score 2):

I would test your theory in a test VM / network if the user should not know where db is located.

Another thing, is you could deploy the app, packaged to the user via horizon or xenapp type methods. All they will see is an icon to click.

I think you could lock down windows to the point where they can't even create a shortcut, or open anything / change anything via group policy. They'll only have access to what they are allowed to have access to.

You could also write a check in powershell and utilize DSC, and have changes reverted back and a report sent to you when it occurs specifying which user did what..

Just some ideas that might help you come to a conclusion

Comment: good ideas. Citrix and the likes are probably geared for big orgs.